# Copy row from Sheet1 and insert at bottom of Sheet2

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Very quick question for someone if you guys could help!

I need a macro to copy data in Cell A1 and B1 from Sheet1 into the last unused cells at the bottom of A:B in sheet2 and then sort by lowest number to highest in column A in sheet2.

Basically i have a master telephone list and rather than letting people loose on the whole list and adding stuff to it, i would rather they write the new number and name in Sheet1 and then that gets added to the bottom of Sheet2 automatically then sorted again in number order.

Comment: so is sheet1 only going to store new entries? at what row is data starting?

Comment: Sheet1 will only be where they add the new entries into Cell A1 (Number) and B1 (Name) then in Sheet2 there is a long list of all the current names and numbers starting from cells A1 and B1 and i need the values from Sheet1 A1 and B1 adding to the very last empty row of Sheet2.

Comment: ok, done. Please accept the answer if its helpful:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data in Sheet1 starts at Row 1 then the below code will copy the data over to Sheet2 below the current data and sort it

```
Sub TransferOver()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim src As Worksheet, trgt As Worksheet
    Set src = Sheets(1): Set trgt = Sheets(2)
    Dim sr As Range, tr As Range, i As Long

    ' 1 is the first row of data
    For i = 1 To src.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set sr = src.Range("A" & i)
        Set tr = trgt.Range("A" & trgt.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        tr = sr
        tr.Offset(0, 1) = sr.Offset(0, 1)
        Set tr = Nothing
        Set sr = Nothing
    Next i

    trgt.Activate
    trgt.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With trgt.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:B" & trgt.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, many thanks! i'm learning more and more each time someone helps me on here so i really do appreciate everything!